# Black Ops 2 having trouble loading multiplayer matches

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When I go on to multiplayer and set up my class and stuff it all works fine, its only when a game tries to load. It's not every game, usually every other game.

Instead of a picture of the map for a background a green colour appears on the screen. It looks like a my game has frozen but i can still press my xbox button on my controller and access everything on the menu. Also in the bottom right corner the little treyarch symbol is still spinning around and around but nothing happens.

The only solution I have found so far is to press the xbox button and return to the xbox home page, then reload the game and that lasts for one or two games then the same problem appears.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have problems reading some very specific game parts from the disc, probably due to scratches. This isn't a general, known bug. You could test if this always happens while loading the same map/s. To fix this you could try installing the game on your harddrive (after cleaning your disc as well as possible), this *might* work as it then does not use the disc for more than constant proof of purchase.

This does not seem to be a problem with your console, since you noticed the main menu does not freeze. If you have modified your console this is another matter. Game shops often offer services that repair scrated discs, something that you can also do at home (not always recommened). Here are some methods: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Non-Working-Xbox-Disk-Work

Good Luck!